# Url pattern "/*" not working in mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web, model-view-controller, web.xml

While using "/*" as url pattern in web.xml in spring mvc, I am not redirected to page. 
Whenever i try below urls, i am getting logger inside the controller methods but i am not getting the page.

> Url tried : http://localhost:8080/mvc-example
>
> Logger : Home Page Requested
>
> Jul 02, 2019 3:57:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/mvc-example/WEB-INF/views/helloAgain.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'mvc-example'

and

> Url tried : http://localhost:8080/mvc-example/hello
>
> Logger : Home hello Page Requested
>
> Jul 02, 2019 3:58:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/mvc-example/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'mvc-example'

This is my project structure :

My Controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Home hello Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printAgainHello(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Home Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Again Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "helloAgain";
    }
}
```

Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>mvc-example</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>mvc-example</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-example-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc-example</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-example-servlet.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.khan" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

When i use "/" only then its working fine as expected but "/*" not working. Making some mistake i guess.

Any one please explain me this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't `hello` a `.jsp` page?
If yes, try changing your controller method's return type as ModelAndView

Comment: yes hello.jsp and helloAgain.jsp page i have under /WEB-INF/views/ folder. I tried with ModelAndView return type but still issue is same. Find below code change :    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView printHello(Model model) {
  System.out.println("Home hello Page Requested");
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("hello");
     modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
     return modelAndView;
 }